Categorical condition for the cokernel of a "diagonal" map
Let $C$ be a category (additive or abelian, say) and $X$ an object. Given a monomorphism of $X$ into $X \oplus X$ (like a diagonal morphism), what kind of conditions are necessary on $C$ to guarantee that the cokernel (assuming it exists) is isomorphic to $X$?
For example, this is true for finite-dimensional vector spaces, but false in many more complicated situations. I'm guessing it also holds for categories enriched over the category of finite-dimensional vector spaces, after adding some finiteness conditions. But am I missing something easy or obvious?
Edit: I'm particularly interested in the case where each object of the category decomposes into a finite direct sum of indecomposable objects.

Let $K(C)$ denote the Grothendieck group of $C$, namely the free abelian group on isomorphism classes $[X]$ of objects in $C$ quotiented by the relations $[X] + [Z] = [Y]$ for every short exact sequence $0 \to X \to Y \to Z \to 0$ in $C$. If a monomorphism $f : X \hookrightarrow X \oplus X$ has a cokernel $Y$ it fits into a short exact sequence
$$0 \to X \xrightarrow{f} X \oplus X \to Y \to 0$$
so we get $[X] = [Y]$ in the Grothendieck group.
In the very nice situation that $C$ is semisimple in the strong sense that every object breaks up into a finite direct sum of simple objects (for example the category of finite-dimensional representations of a finite or compact group $G$ or a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ over an appropriate field), then the Grothendieck group is free abelian on the simple objects, so an object $X$ is determined up to isomorphism by its image $[X]$ in the Grothendieck group. In that case your desired condition holds.
But this is very uncommon; conversely, if objects are determined up to isomorphism by their image in the Grothendieck group, then short exact sequences in $C$ must "split up to isomorphism" in the sense that if $0 \to X \to Y \to Z \to 0$ is a short exact sequence then $Y$ must be isomorphic to $X \oplus Z$ (although I don't know if it's necessary that the short exact sequence must itself split). So any abelian category in which there are any nontrivial extensions in the strong sense of an extension $Y$ as above which is not abstractly isomorphic to $X \oplus Z$ cannot have this property (for example the category of finite-dimensional representations of $\mathbb{Z}$).
Here is an example of what can happen in general. Let $A = K[x, y]/xy$, $K$ a field, and let $C$ be the category of $A$-modules. Let $X = A$ be the regular module, and consider the map $f : X \to X^2$ given by
$$X \ni p \mapsto (xp, yp) \in X^2.$$
By construction, $f$ is injective but neither of its components is injective. $f$ also has the property that after tensoring with the evaluation homomorphism $K[x, y]/xy \to K$ sending $x$ and $y$ to zero, it is equal to zero, but $X \otimes_A K$ is $1$-dimensional and so $X^2$ is $2$-dimensional; it follows that the cokernel is not generated by one element, so cannot be isomorphic to $X$.

I think you mean $[X] + [Z] \sim [Y]$?

@Naïm: yes, thanks.

Thanks very much, this is very helpful! Suppose we're instead dealing with a category where each object decomposes into a finite direct sum of indecomposable objects, like a Krull-Schmidt category. Does the statement hold for $X$ indecomposable? Does it hold if we furthermore assume that nonisomorphic indecomposable objects have different images in the Grothendieck group?

@user39269: I don't know. I would guess that there is a counterexample similar to the one above but with $A$ finite-dimensional but I wasn't able to find one.
